# Place the Static HTML Page in kibana Dashboard

Tags: kibana, kibana-5

I need to add the Static HTML file in Kibana dashboard.where i can hold my HTML file in Kibana.
Note:Kibana version 5.6.3
I come across some kibana plugin like Kibana-html-plugin,kibana5-html-plugin , but it wont support for my kibana version 5.6.3.
i already change the package.json file but it wont help.
is there any otherway to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import marked from 'marked';
import uiModules from 'ui/modules';
import 'angular-sanitize';

marked.setOptions({
  gfm: true, // Github-flavored markdown
  sanitize: true // Sanitize HTML tags
});


const module = uiModules.get('kibana/markdown_vis', ['kibana']);
module.controller('KbnMarkdownVisController', function ($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.$watch('vis.params.markdown', function (html) {
    if (!html) return;
    $scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
  });
});
```

at last, I found the solution.
Paste the above code in kibana/src/core_plugins/markdown_vis/public/markdown_vis_controller.js

Comment: this is from http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2016/11/22/embedding-javascript-and-html-into-kibana-5-x/
just for the reference